# How to change the default timeout for the Jenkins Artifactory plugin in a Multibranch Pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline build job that is uploading a rather large number of big files to Artifactory, and therefore the upload step is taking longer than the default 5 minute limit defined in the Artifactory Jenkins plugin:

```
src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/ArtifactoryServer.java:    private static final int DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 300;    // 5 Minutes
```

How can I specify a longer timeout in my Jenkinsfile so my build jobs can get successfully uploaded and stop failing?

Comment: can you please provide the Jenkinsfile snippet you have defined atm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented here: [HAP-893](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-893).

The short answer is that, for now, this is not possible for pipeline jobs.